# Windows Live Writer fails to start

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-writer

I installed windows live writer and configured it to connect to my xmlrpc enabled blog engine. After doing so, it threw an unrecoverable error and closed down.

After attempting to restart windows live writer, it throws the following exception each time:

> Description:
>   Windows Live Writer has encountered a problem: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
>
> Problem signature:
>   Problem Event Name: WindowsLiveWriter
>   Problem Signature 01: CreateThis
>   Problem Signature 02: 115 
>   Problem Signature 03: System.UriFormatException
>   Problem Signature 04: 15.4.3555.308
>   Problem Signature 05: 2.0.50727.5456
>   Problem Signature 06: Windows Live Writer
>   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>   Locale ID: 1033

Since I was unable to start windows live writer at all, I tried uninstalling it and removing all files associated with it in my "C:/users/[username]/appdata" folder. After that, I re-installed it and still get the error every time I try to launch the application.

Does anyone know how I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. I started rooting through the registry to see if the blog data was stored in there (since it wasn't being reset with a re-install).

This is what I found:
Somehow, the url for my blog wasn't stored correctly, and that's what was causing the error. (Probably my fault) I found the registry entry where the blog information was stored for windows live writer:

`HKEY_USERS\[Current User]\Software\Microsoft\Windows Live\Writer\Weblogs\[hashed folder]`

In regedit, clicking on the hashed folder name revealed the "HomepageURL" entry, which I was able to correct. After I did that, it launched fine.